# How to get specific content from cross-domain http request

Tags: php, jquery, url

There is a Dutch news website at: [nu.nl](http://www.nu.nl/) 
I am very interested in getting the first url headline which is resided over her:

```
<h3 class="hdtitle">
          <a style="" onclick="NU.AT.internalLink(this, event);" xtclib="position1_article_1" href="/buitenland/2880252/griekse-hotels-ontruimd-bosbranden.html">
            Griekse hotels ontruimd om bosbranden            <img src="/images/i18n/nl/slideshow/bt_fotograaf.png" class="vidlinkicon" alt="">          </a>
        </h3>
```

So my question is how do I get this url? Can I do this with Jquery? I would think not because it is not on my server. So maybe I would have to use PHP? Where do I start...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tested and working

Because http://www.nu.nl is not your site, you can do a ***cross-domain*** `GET` using the `PHP` proxy method, otherwise you will get this kind of error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.nu.nl/. Origin
>   http://yourdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

First of all use this file in your server at **PHP** side:

**proxy.php (Updated)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['site'])){
  $f = fopen($_GET['site'], 'r');
  $html = '';
  while (!feof($f)) {
    $html .= fread($f, 24000);
  }
  fclose($f);
  echo $html;
}
?>
```

Now, at javascript side using **jQuery** you can do the following:

*(Just to know I am using `prop();` cause I use jQuery **1.7.2** version. So, if you are using a version before **1.6.x**, try `attr();` instead)*

```
$(function(){

   var site = 'http://www.nu.nl';

   $.get('proxy.php', { site:site }, function(data){

      var href = $(data).find('.hdtitle').first().children(':first-child').prop('href');
      var url = href.split('/');
      href = href.replace(url[2], 'nu.nl');

      // Put the 'href' inside your div as a link
      $('#myDiv').html('<a href="' + href + '" target="_blank">' + href + '</a>');

   }, 'html');

});
```

As you can see, the request is in your domain but is a kind of tricky thing so you won't get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error again!

---

### Update

If you want to get all headlines `href` as you wrote in comments, you can do the following:

***Just change jQuery code like this...***

```
$(function(){

   var site = 'http://www.nu.nl';

   $.get('proxy.php', { site:site }, function(data){

        // get all html headlines
        headlines = $(data).find('.hdtitle');

        // get 'href' attribute of each headline and put it inside div
        headlines.map(function(elem, index){ 
            href = $(this).children(':first-child').prop('href');
            url = href.split('/');
            href = href.replace(url[2], 'nu.nl');
            $('#myDiv').append('<a href="' + href + '" target="_blank">' + href + '</a><br/>');
        });

   }, 'html');

});
```

**and use updated `proxy.php` file (for both cases, 1 or all headlines).**

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Incredible, thank you very very much :) (do you perhaps have any idea about how to attach the real domain (nu.nl) to the output instead of my own site)

Comment: Hi there, Im having some problems with the script..I cant seem to get anything else other than 1 url...Can you please make some time for me and tell me how to get all the urls of the page. I would really appreciate it if you could take another look at it and help me out.

Comment: Well, the script works according to your question (when you wrote that only the first headline is needed). If you now need all of them just remove the ".first()" in jQuery code, then the variable "href" will become an array and finally do a ".map() - jQuery method" or loop to your variable. Then inside the ".map()" or loop just put the href inside the div like when doing just for one headline.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding:) I tried many things but nothing worked for me..I think this is the part that is giving me broblems `while(strpos($html, 'position1_article_1') === FALSE)` Can I somehow get rid of it or change position1_article_1 in 'body' or something like that? Of course I will now try what you have suggested but I think the part I mentioned is going to cause me problems.

Comment: @Youss check the code from updated part, also from `proxy.php`, it will capture all `html` source code now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [simplehtmldom library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get that **link**

Something like that

```
$html = file_get_html('website_link');
echo $html->getElementById("hdtitle")->childNodes(1)->getAttribute('href');
```

read more [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: This looks really simple, I hope it is in reality (:

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested RSS, but unfortunately the headline you're looking for doesn't seem to appear there.

```
<?

$f = fopen('http://www.nu.nl', 'r');
$html = '';
while(strpos($html, 'position1_article_1') === FALSE)
    $html .= fread($f, 24000);
fclose($f);
$pos = strpos($html, 'position1_article_1');
$urlleft = substr($html, $pos + 27);
$url = substr($urlleft, 0, strpos($urlleft, '"'));
echo 'http://www.nu.nl' . $url;

?>
```

Outputs: http://www.nu.nl/buitenland/2880252/griekse-hotels-ontruimd-bosbranden.html

Comment: This looks promising, still have to test it

Comment: Can you explain to me how the output would be //www...etc when in the document the url starts out with /buitenland/28...etc ??

Comment: Because `echo 'http://www.nu.nl' . $url;` adds `http://www.nu.nl` to the left before printing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up a jQuery bot to scrape the page through a browser (Google Chrome extensions allow for this functionality):

```
// print out the found anchor link's href attribute
console.log($('.hdtitle').find('a').attr('href'));
```

If you want to use PHP, you'll need to scrape the page for this `href` link. Use libraries such as `SimpleTest` to accomplish this. The best way to periodically scrape is to link your PHP script to a `cronjob` as well.

**SimpleTest**: http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php

**cronjob**: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Good luck!

Comment: But this will only work if the OP would have access to this site. I assume he wants to crawl it. So maybe a solution with an iframe or php could help.

Comment: but this url not on his server, i think he need to get that <a> element with php and then get the link

Comment: What about cURL running as a cron task?

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL to retrieve the page. Then, use the following function to parse the string you've provided;

```
preg_match("/<a.*?href\=\"(.*?)\".*?>/is",$text,$matches);
```

The result URL will be in the $matches array.