# cross-domain GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

Someone was nice to write me a script that allows to retrieve data from cross domain site. The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['site'])){
  $f = fopen($_GET['site'], 'r');
  $html = '';
  while(strpos($html, 'position1_article_1') === FALSE)
    $html .= fread($f, 24000);
  fclose($f);
  echo $html;
}
?>
```

Which is saved as **proxy.php** The Jquery part looks like this:

```
$(function(){

   var site = 'http://www.nu.nl';

   $.get('proxy.php', { site:site }, function(data){

      var href = $(data).find('.hdtitle').first().children(':first-child').prop('href');
      var url = href.split('/');
      href = href.replace(url[2], 'nu.nl');

      // Put the 'href' inside your div as a link
      $('#myDiv').html('<a href="' + href + '" target="_blank">' + href + '</a>');

   }, 'html');

});
```

The problem is that I cant figure out how to get all the 'a' in the body or certain part like h2, h3 etc. Can someone please break it down to me? For instance; what do I have to change in order to get all the href in the page?

Comment: I'm not too sure in what you're trying to do, could you re-word it slightly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627489/php-parse-html-code

Comment: @ShaneCurran I want to do several things with the script, but I cant figure out how it works(I dont know PHP) So if someone could explain to me how to get all href of the body, then this could bring me a step closer to understandin how it works.

Comment: I dont know how your html looks like but you need to change this line, var href = $(data).find('a').prop('href'); should give you all the a tags.

Comment: @defau1t I think I wouldn't because of this line: while(strpos($html, 'position1_article_1') === FALSE)

Comment: That php code is doing nothing more than loading the html you point at, and stopping when it finds the string "position1_article_1" in the response. If you want to parse the html see @ethrbunny's comment, or one of the 10s/100s of duplicates where parsing html with php is discussed.

Comment: @Youss you don't need to make duplicate questions, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887788/1178686 it is solved now.

Comment: @Oscar Jara Thanks for taking another look at it:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this : `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

And use it like that :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if(isset($_GET['site'])){
  $f = fopen($_GET['site'], 'r');
  $html = '';
  while(strpos($html, 'position1_article_1') === FALSE)
    $html .= fread($f, 24000);
  fclose($f);
  echo $html;
}
?>
```

Enjoy !

Comment: How is adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` going to do anything at all when the php request is to the same domain as the page loading the js file?